# NetBeans FTP log output, upload on save

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp, synchronization, netbeans-7

(*Realized maybe this is better suited to SuperUser, sorry if it is*)

Using NetBeans 7.0 (*Build 201104080000*) and have just created a remote project for the first time to continue on a (*now*) remotely located PHP project. (*Much better than **FileZilla** + **Notepad++***)

Anyways, when I perform an initial batch upload/download, NetBeans spits out a nice log of the FTP activity, which is all good.

However, since I have the project set to **upload on save**, whenever I save a given file, I receive no output, though it does upload. Explicit uploading/downloading produces output.

I'm concerned in the event of errors or whatnot (*or syncing large files which could take awhile*) that I'll not know what's going on.

I'm not using SVN (*please suppress the urge to advise; I know, I know, I'll figure out SVN for further projects with 2+ developers*) but regardless, does anyone have any knowledge of what to do to produce output on save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

control + 4
or Window => Output

Comment: Thanks **brain_damage**; The problem wasn't displaying the output *window*; rather, having any output data *generated* when uploading on save. Curiously though, without any (*deliberate*) changes my output window began producing FTP data, when I save. So problem solved, but I haven't the slightest idea why. I haven't made any configuration changes, to NetBeans or the project's FTP connection data. Any ideas?

Comment: i never had this problem, are you sure you were looking at the output window before? theres similar windows in nb that looks like this this one. also you might had a filter on (control+G or right click+filter) that supress lines by a filter..in that window